# Where is the source code that changes grid line styles using rcParams?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for the source code that changes grid line styles using `rcParams`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['grid.color'] = '#999999'
rcParams['grid.linestyle'] = '-'


x = x_data
y = y_data

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 6))

ax.plot(x,y)

plt.grid(b=True)

plt.show()
```

In this example the following code:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['grid.color'] = '#999999'
rcParams['grid.linestyle'] = '-'
```

changes the grid color and linestyle. But where is the source code that deals with this? (asking because I want to modify it so that I could add `grid.minor.color` and `grid.major.color` to `rcParams` too, allowing me to customize minor and major grid line styles more conveniently).

Thanks!

Comment: Modifying the source code is a bad idea for a number of reasons, it would be much better to write a wrapper which draws the grid according to the major and minor colors you want

Comment: @WilliamMiller I actually wanted to contribute to open source projects, and there was an open issue regarding this feature (hence wanting to modify source code). I can't pinpoint which part of the code handles setting the actual gridline colors based on the rcParams value though. I tried to trace, for example, `plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')` to it's source code, but I arrived at this file and can't find where the actual source code that deals with customizing grid lines is: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py

Comment: @WilliamMiller any idea?

Comment: The code where the parameter is used is in [/axis.py Line 135](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3fe3d1a33608977d7b7c09e37eb8a966c58e781a/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L135-L143)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok thanks! That's for tick right? I was looking for setting color using `rcParam` values for grid lines. When a user changes the value of a grid line, is it a tick's values being updated? The link you provided, is that the source code that runs when a grid line style / color is updated?

Comment: That's the code that is run when the grid is created. Hence it will take over the rcParams. If you want to update the grid of an existing axes, you would not use rcParams.